# Join operation returning partial results in Databricks

Tags: join, databricks, databricks-sql

I have two dataframes in Databricks: a parquet file and an uploaded csv dataframe

Running a particular sql join operation in databricks, I get partial results (~20% of rows are returned and no error message) and the query log shows a skipped job.

I have verified that the join works perfectly using vlookups in excel and running a join in alteryx.

Any ideas why it works in every other tool but not in databricks?

joining a small table to a large table and I have tried a broadcast join with same results

Comment: please provide code sample, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both to tables and then apply the join operation using sql